# Javascript array declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays

What object will this create? I've never seen this declaration before so I'm just wondering.

```
`myArray([]);
 for(someValue = 0; someValue < someOtherValue; i++)
     myArray.push(something[i]);
`
```

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

EDIT : I Update the code some more to gime some more info.
myArray doesn't seem like a function to me in the code. This is used in an AjaxCall. Some lines after it is used like this

So unless I missed something I don't think it is a function.

Comment: Probably an object of type `myArray`.

Comment: `[]` is an array literal. What is that `myArray` function?

Comment: it's a function call with an empty array as an argument

Comment: Exactly what I'm wondering. Looks like an array to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is an empty array literal and it's being passed to a function `myArray` which accepts an array as an argument. This is not a declaration, it's just a function call. It could be defined like this:

```
function myArray(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
}

var array = []; // empty array to be filled later

myArray(array);
```

This fills the array with the numbers from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function `myArray` and passing in any empty array literal, which is defined by these: `[]`. What's the `myArray` function look like?

Answer (score 1):

If `myArray` is a function you are calling then `[]` will pass an empty array as the first argument to it

Its same as doing

```
var arr = new Array();
myArray(arr);
```